# Azure Web App. SFTP Doesn't Display Files

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

We published our application to Azure Web App via Azure Dev Ops. When we SFTP into the Web App we can only see hostingstart.html, yet side loads and we can see proper files in Kuded and App Service Editor. There is only 1 deployment slot in our Azure Web App. How is that possible

Comment: Check if WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is set to "1" in application settings. This setting doesn't extract the package content to the D:\home\site\wwwroot directory of your app. Instead, it uploads the ZIP file as-is to D:\home\data\SitePackages, and creates a packagename.txt in the same directory, that contains the name of the ZIP package to load at runtime. 
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package

Comment: Yes, WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is set to "1". So, our Web App runs as ZIP package. I didn't know about this feature. Thank you. Please, move this comment to answer. Also this brings another question how can we avoid that behavior in our case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59886757/azure-devops-runs-web-app-as-zip-package-instead-of-zip-deploy

Comment: @Gaurav Kumar You can convert your comment into an answer, it can help other community members who get the same issues more easily to find the solution,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is set to "1" in application settings. This setting doesn't extract the package content to the D:\home\site\wwwroot directory of your app. Instead, it uploads the ZIP file as-is to D:\home\data\SitePackages, and creates a packagename.txt in the same directory, that contains the name of the ZIP package to load at runtime.

See: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package